# DAHDI Installation on Slicehost Woes

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk

I'm trying to get DAHDI installed for Asterisk on my Slicehost slice...

I start off `sudo apt-get install dahdi-dkms dahdi-linux`

Which partially fails with this in the install log:

```
Setting up dahdi-dkms (1:2.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Loading new dahdi-2.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 2.6.33.5-rscloud
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

This seems to be because I do not have the kernel source installed. However, with Slicehost, kernel sources are only available through http://kernel.slicehost.com... in my case, this is the kernel source I need: http://kernel.slicehost.com/2.6.33.5-rscloud/patched_source/2.6.33.5-rscloud.tar.bz2

Those kernel sources--so far as I'm aware--do not exist in any `apt-get` repository.

So I download and extract the source, but I don't think it is "installed" the same way as if I had gone through `apt-get install kernel-source` or whatever, and so I keep getting this error when trying to install `dahdi`.

How can I "install" the Slicehost compressed kernel code of my system so that I can install `dahdi` through `apt-get`??

I am running Ubuntu Lucid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the process.  Prepare the kernel first:

```
wget -q http://kernel.slicehost.com/2.6.33.5-rscloud/patched_source/2.6.33.5-rscloud.tar.gz
mkdir /usr/src/kernels/
tar xzf 2.6.33.5-rscloud.tar.gz -C /usr/src/kernels/
cd /usr/src/kernels/linux-2.6.33.5/
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
make oldconfig && make modules_prepare
```

Once that's done, just follow the documentation provided with the dahdi module in the Makefile:

```
cd ~
svn co http://svn.digium.com/svn/dahdi/linux/trunk dahdi-kernel
cd dahdi-kernel
KSRC=/usr/src/kernels/linux-2.6.33.5/ make install
```

You should then be all set:

```
# modprobe dahdi
# lsmod | grep dahdi
dahdi                 186793  0 
crc_ccitt               1203  1 dahdi
# modinfo dahdi
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.33.5-rscloud/dahdi/dahdi.ko
version:        SVN-trunk-r8983
alias:          dahdi_dummy
license:        GPL v2
description:    DAHDI Telephony Interface
author:         Mark Spencer <markster@digium.com>
srcversion:     B1B1151F11B45BEFBEEE0B0
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.33.5-rscloud SMP mod_unload 
parm:           debug:int
parm:           deftaps:int
```

I just did this on a slice running Debian Lenny and 2.6.33.5-rscloud.

Comment: "When you build the dahdi module, you'll need to specify the path to your kernel source that you just prepared." How do I do this??

Comment: Check my updated post above.

Comment: Sweet awesomeness! That was EXACTLY what I was looking for! I've been banging my head over this four hours... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this article?

http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/18/downloading-and-using-kernel-source-code-2-6-32-12-and-newer-on-ubuntu

Follow the steps to install the headers and prepare for module installation, and hopefully those will let you install the package.

Often packages expect to find kernel source in /usr/src, so if it complains after you unpack it there and do the headers and module_prepare stuff, try making a symlink from /usr/src/linux to where you unpacked the source.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that article (where I got the kernel.slicehost.com mentioned in my question). I have downloaded the source, uncompressed it, and ran the headers and modules_prepare stuff and all that jazz... yet I still don't have a clear answer on how to actually compile dahdi--either through apt-get or manually--with this kernel source. That's what I really need to know!